# Unexpected CSS behavior for borders

Tags: html, css

I have a simple button with hover animation. as you see in the code I set the border to be `none`. but unexpectedly when you click on the button the black border appears. if you click anywhere on the page the black border disappears again.

What causes this and how to fix it?

```css
.voiceAcceptedClass {
  position:absolute;
  z-index: 10002;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: #006aff;
  padding: 0.325vw 3.906vw;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 1.2vw;
  top: 40vw;
  width: 30vw;
  text-align: center;
  border: none;
}

#voiceAccepted{
  left: 10.3vw;
  top:44vw;
}

.voiceAcceptedClass:hover {
  text-shadow: 0 0 0.39vw rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0.33vw 2.6vw -0.65vw rgba(0,0,0,0.57);
  transition: all 0.4s ease 0s;
}

/* Hover state animation applied here */
.voiceAcceptedClass:hover { 
  -webkit-animation: hover 1200ms linear 2 alternate;
  animation: hover 1200ms linear 2 alternate;
}

/* Active state animation applied here */
.voiceAcceptedClass:active {
  -webkit-animation: active 1200ms ease 1 alternate;
  animation: active 1200ms ease 1 alternate; 
  background: #5F9BE0;
}


/* Hover state animation keyframes below */

@-webkit-keyframes hover { 
  0% { -webkit-transform: matrix3d(1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); transform: matrix3d(1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); }
  1.8% { -webkit-transform: matrix3d(1.016, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.037, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); transform: matrix3d(1.016, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.037, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); }
  3.5% { -webkit-transform: matrix3d(1.033, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.094, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); transform: matrix3d(1.033, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.094, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); }
  4.7% { -webkit-transform: matrix3d(1.045, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.129, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); transform: matrix3d(1.045, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.129, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); }
  5.31% { -webkit-transform: matrix3d(1.051, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.142, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); transform: matrix3d(1.051, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.142, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); }
  7.01% { -webkit-transform: matrix3d(1.068, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.158, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); transform: matrix3d(1.068, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.158, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); }
  8.91% { -webkit-transform: matrix3d(1.084, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.141, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); transform: matrix3d(1.084, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.141, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); }
  9.41% { -webkit-transform: matrix3d(1.088, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.132, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); transform: matrix3d(1.088, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.132, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); }
  10.71% { -webkit-transform: matrix3d(1.097, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.107, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); transform: matrix3d(1.097, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.107, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); }
  12.61% { -webkit-transform: matrix3d(1.108, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.077, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); transform: matrix3d(1.108, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.077, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); }
  14.11% { -webkit-transform: matrix3d(1.114, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.067, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); transform: matrix3d(1.114, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.067, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); }
  14.41% { -webkit-transform: matrix3d(1.115, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.067, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); transform: matrix3d(1.115, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.067, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); }
  16.32% { -webkit-transform: matrix3d(1.119, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.077, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); transform: matrix3d(1.119, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.077, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); }
  18.12% { -webkit-transform: matrix3d(1.121, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.096, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); transform: matrix3d(1.121, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.096, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); }
  18.72% { -webkit-transform: matrix3d(1.121, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.102, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); transform: matrix3d(1.121, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.102, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); }
  20.02% { -webkit-transform: matrix3d(1.121, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.113, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); transform: matrix3d(1.121, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.113, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); }
  21.82% { -webkit-transform: matrix3d(1.119, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.119, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); transform: matrix3d(1.119, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.119, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); }
  24.32% { -webkit-transform: matrix3d(1.115, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.11, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); transform: matrix3d(1.115, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.11, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); }
  25.53% { -webkit-transform: matrix3d(1.113, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.102, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); transform: matrix3d(1.113, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.102, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); }
  29.23% { -webkit-transform: matrix3d(1.106, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.089, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); transform: matrix3d(1.106, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.089, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); }
  29.93% { -webkit-transform: matrix3d(1.105, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.09, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); transform: matrix3d(1.105, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.09, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); }
  35.54% { -webkit-transform: matrix3d(1.098, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.105, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); transform: matrix3d(1.098, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.105, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); }
  36.64% { -webkit-transform: matrix3d(1.097, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.106, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); transform: matrix3d(1.097, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.106, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); }
  41.04% { -webkit-transform: matrix3d(1.096, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.099, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); transform: matrix3d(1.096, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.099, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); }
  44.04% { -webkit-transform: matrix3d(1.096, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.097, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); transform: matrix3d(1.096, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.097, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); }
  51.45% { -webkit-transform: matrix3d(1.099, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.102, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); transform: matrix3d(1.099, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.102, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); }
  52.15% { -webkit-transform: matrix3d(1.099, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.102, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); transform: matrix3d(1.099, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.102, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); }
  58.86% { -webkit-transform: matrix3d(1.101, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.099, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); transform: matrix3d(1.101, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.099, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); }
  63.26% { -webkit-transform: matrix3d(1.101, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); transform: matrix3d(1.101, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); }
  66.27% { -webkit-transform: matrix3d(1.101, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.101, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); transform: matrix3d(1.101, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.101, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); }
  73.77% { -webkit-transform: matrix3d(1.1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); transform: matrix3d(1.1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); }
  81.18% { -webkit-transform: matrix3d(1.1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); transform: matrix3d(1.1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); }
  85.49% { -webkit-transform: matrix3d(1.1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); transform: matrix3d(1.1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); }
  88.59% { -webkit-transform: matrix3d(1.1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); transform: matrix3d(1.1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); }
  96% { -webkit-transform: matrix3d(1.1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); transform: matrix3d(1.1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); }
  100% { -webkit-transform: matrix3d(1.1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); transform: matrix3d(1.1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); } 
}

@keyframes hover { 
  0% { -webkit-transform: matrix3d(1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); transform: matrix3d(1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); }
  1.8% { -webkit-transform: matrix3d(1.016, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.037, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); transform: matrix3d(1.016, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.037, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); }
  3.5% { -webkit-transform: matrix3d(1.033, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.094, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); transform: matrix3d(1.033, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.094, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); }
  4.7% { -webkit-transform: matrix3d(1.045, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.129, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); transform: matrix3d(1.045, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.129, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); }
  5.31% { -webkit-transform: matrix3d(1.051, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.142, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); transform: matrix3d(1.051, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.142, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); }
  7.01% { -webkit-transform: matrix3d(1.068, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.158, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); transform: matrix3d(1.068, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.158, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); }
  8.91% { -webkit-transform: matrix3d(1.084, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.141, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); transform: matrix3d(1.084, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.141, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); }
  9.41% { -webkit-transform: matrix3d(1.088, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.132, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); transform: matrix3d(1.088, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.132, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); }
  10.71% { -webkit-transform: matrix3d(1.097, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.107, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); transform: matrix3d(1.097, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.107, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); }
  12.61% { -webkit-transform: matrix3d(1.108, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.077, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); transform: matrix3d(1.108, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.077, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); }
  14.11% { -webkit-transform: matrix3d(1.114, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.067, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); transform: matrix3d(1.114, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.067, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); }
  14.41% { -webkit-transform: matrix3d(1.115, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.067, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); transform: matrix3d(1.115, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.067, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); }
  16.32% { -webkit-transform: matrix3d(1.119, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.077, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); transform: matrix3d(1.119, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.077, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); }
  18.12% { -webkit-transform: matrix3d(1.121, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.096, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); transform: matrix3d(1.121, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.096, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); }
  18.72% { -webkit-transform: matrix3d(1.121, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.102, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); transform: matrix3d(1.121, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.102, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); }
  20.02% { -webkit-transform: matrix3d(1.121, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.113, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); transform: matrix3d(1.121, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.113, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); }
  21.82% { -webkit-transform: matrix3d(1.119, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.119, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); transform: matrix3d(1.119, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.119, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); }
  24.32% { -webkit-transform: matrix3d(1.115, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.11, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); transform: matrix3d(1.115, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.11, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); }
  25.53% { -webkit-transform: matrix3d(1.113, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.102, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); transform: matrix3d(1.113, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.102, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); }
  29.23% { -webkit-transform: matrix3d(1.106, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.089, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); transform: matrix3d(1.106, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.089, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); }
  29.93% { -webkit-transform: matrix3d(1.105, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.09, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); transform: matrix3d(1.105, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.09, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); }
  35.54% { -webkit-transform: matrix3d(1.098, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.105, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); transform: matrix3d(1.098, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.105, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); }
  36.64% { -webkit-transform: matrix3d(1.097, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.106, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); transform: matrix3d(1.097, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.106, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); }
  41.04% { -webkit-transform: matrix3d(1.096, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.099, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); transform: matrix3d(1.096, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.099, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); }
  44.04% { -webkit-transform: matrix3d(1.096, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.097, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); transform: matrix3d(1.096, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.097, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); }
  51.45% { -webkit-transform: matrix3d(1.099, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.102, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); transform: matrix3d(1.099, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.102, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); }
  52.15% { -webkit-transform: matrix3d(1.099, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.102, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); transform: matrix3d(1.099, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.102, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); }
  58.86% { -webkit-transform: matrix3d(1.101, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.099, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); transform: matrix3d(1.101, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.099, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); }
  63.26% { -webkit-transform: matrix3d(1.101, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); transform: matrix3d(1.101, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); }
  66.27% { -webkit-transform: matrix3d(1.101, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.101, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); transform: matrix3d(1.101, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.101, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); }
  73.77% { -webkit-transform: matrix3d(1.1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); transform: matrix3d(1.1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); }
  81.18% { -webkit-transform: matrix3d(1.1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); transform: matrix3d(1.1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); }
  85.49% { -webkit-transform: matrix3d(1.1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); transform: matrix3d(1.1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); }
  88.59% { -webkit-transform: matrix3d(1.1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); transform: matrix3d(1.1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); }
  96% { -webkit-transform: matrix3d(1.1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); transform: matrix3d(1.1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); }
  100% { -webkit-transform: matrix3d(1.1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); transform: matrix3d(1.1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1); } 
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8"> 
</head>

<body> 

<button class="voiceAcceptedClass" id="voiceAccepted">Accept Selected Voices & Continue</button>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: this outline, not border

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That isn't a border, it is an [`outline`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/outline) and it is an [important accessibility feature](https://a11yproject.com/posts/never-remove-css-outlines/) that tells people where the focus is on the document.

You can remove it in the same way as a border, but the accessibility implications mean you *shouldn't* (at least unless you replace it with some other clearly visible focus marker).